# Node restart is prohibitively slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nodemon

So I use `tsc-watch` to watch my file and recompile typescript when changes are detected.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./dist/index.js",
    "start:dev": "rimraf ./dist && mkdir ./dist && cp -R ./src/templates ./dist/templates && tsc-watch --noClear --onSuccess \"yarn start\"",
```

This all works, and the incremental compliation from `tsc-watch` seems to be very fast,  however the `node ./dist/index.js` step takes 15-20 seconds. Which I believe is pretty slow, at least relative to other backend technologies I've used.

```
import { loadConfig } from "./config";
import createServer from "./server";

const start = async () => {
  const config = loadConfig();
  const server = await createServer(config);
  server.listen({
    port: config.mount.port,
    host: config.mount.hostname
  });
};

start();
```

What could I do to improve this reload time?

Comment: Your application must be massive for it to be this slow. You could try some conditional imports instead of every import at the top of each file to delay loading some stuff until it's needed (or at least just at a delay).

Comment: It's actually a very small app... Thank you... I'll look into that.

Comment: If it's really small, then don't follow my advice. Something is seriously wrong. Node applications shouldn't take that long to start.

Comment: What does `loadConfig`/`createServer` do? Which one is slow? Is there anything external they connect to?